# Which FFmpeg video codec is natively supported in Windows 10 and Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, video, codec

I need to generate a video that will run on Windows 10 with Windows Media Player without having to install any codec or anything else. I plan to generate that video using flags like the below.

What codec should I choose for maximum compatibility and minimum size (not care about quality)? Also no audio needed.

```
-stream_loop 5 
-i image.png
-movflags faststart 
-vf "setpts=1*PTS, scale=1:1"
```

Comment: “What codec should I choose for maximum compatibility and minimum size (not care about quality)?” That might simply be MP4.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?